# Do custom template tags cause a database query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-template-filters

I am using 5 - 6 custom template tags.

Each one of them is similar to the following:

```
@register.filter(name = 'time_left')
def time_left(obj):
    if not obj:
        return -1
    if not obj.has_offer_expired():
        return obj.time_left()
    return None
```

I have this in my `models.py`:

```
def has_offer_expired(self):
    return self.end_time <= timezone.now()

def time_left(self):
    return int((self.end_time - timezone.now()).total_seconds())
```

Whenever the template tag is used, `{{ offer | time_left }}`, will it cause a database query? Or, `offer` is passed to the template tag function and its attributes are used without causing any extra db query?

A detailed explanation of the working of template tags behind the scenes would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

**Edit: Please add a reason before down voting the question!**

Comment: Why would they cause a database query? If `offer` is already fetched, then no. If however `offer` contains attributes, etc. wity lazy loading, it will just work like any other query, and thus fetch related objects.

Comment: `offer` is already fetched with all its attributes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you work around data in your template tags.

Basically when you load a row or more from database, you'll have everything about it. On the other hand if you need to access relations then you will send another query which you can also combine that query to the first one using **prefetch** methods.

Calls like calling a m2m field can cause a new query to the database but if you need the main attributes, then the same object on template will be passed and same data will be available without an extra query.

[prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)